# Android application that uses web view

Tags: android

i am using a web view in my android app,how can i remove " Web Page not available" from my android app when there is no internet access

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
         ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
               for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                      return true;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         return false;
      }
```

This piece of code says if there is internet or not.. if there is no internet then you can skip the things as required..

Answer (score 0):

Check if `connection.getResponseCode() == 200` or not and redirect to static page.